# Javascript - is an anonymous function used as a callback created multiple times?

Tags: javascript

When an anonymous function is passed as a callback to something like map, is the function object created only once, or multiple times?

```
const newArray = myArray.map(item => item + 100);
```

Is there a benefit (other than debugging) for creating a named function if it will only be used as a callback in that one case?

```
function add100(item) {
  return item + 100;
}
const newArray = myArray.map(add100);
```

Comment: The question you linked to was about a factory function that does return an other function `function gen() { return function inner() {} }` and was asking if a new `inner` gets created everytime `gen` is called. Your case is totally different in that nothing does generate a function in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is only created once. The interpreter first has to parse each item in the argument list, and then each argument is passed to the function - the arguments don't get re-parsed every time `.map`'s internals run. (the arguments couldn't get re-parsed with *any* function - a function doesn't control how it gets called.)

```js
const myArray = [1, 2];
const newArray = myArray.map((console.log('argument being parsed'), item => item + 100));
console.log(newArray);
```

A named function is useful not only for debugging, but for readability as well. For something trivial like `add100`, it may not be useful, but imagine if the function was 10-20 lines long - naming it could be useful, otherwise one would have to look through each line to figure out what exactly the callback is doing. Even if you're not debugging a problem, code readability is (usually) very useful.

Or, of course, you could describe what the function does in a comment.

A named function can also call itself, whereas an anonymous function can't, but that's very unusual to see in a `.map` callback.

```js
const arr = [2, 3];
function bigSquare(item) {
  const result = item ** 2;
  return result < 100
  ? bigSquare(result)
  : result;
}

console.log(arr.map(bigSquare));
```

The interpreter will only create a function while it attempts to parse a `function` (or `=>`) keyword, or when `.bind` is called, or when `new Function` is called.

Comment: But I even wonder what really happens under the hood when we do change the `this` of a function (e.g from `thisArg` argument we have in Array.map or forEach). Sure it doesn't create a new Function object, but somehow, the function may be different for the interpreter... Well I digress.

Comment: @Kaiido I'd think it basically just uses the internal equivalent of `.call`, right? It doesn't need a new function, it just needs to "call" the existing function with the appropriate `this` value. I remember that creating functions (like with `.bind`) is relatively expensive, whereas `.call` is cheap

Answer (score 1):

In your case above, `add100` is only created once.

```
function add100(item) {
  return item + 100;
}
const newArray = myArray.map(add100);
```

Or even this,

```
const newArray = myArray.map(function add100(item) {
  return item + 100;
});
```

> Is there a benefit (other than debugging) for creating a named
>   function if it will only be used as a callback in that one case?

There is! for instance, you can reuse that `add100` function.

Or for another case, let's say you want to add an event listener and you want to remove it in later in the future, you will need that function object reference to remove it.

**E.g.**

```
// Add the event listener
window.addEventListener('scroll', add100);

// Remove the event listener
window.removeEventListener('scroll', add100);
```

Above will work fine, however if you do this;

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function add100() { /* do something */ });
window.removeEventListener('scroll', function add100() { /* do something */ });
```

You will never be able to remove the event listener that once you added to window.

Comment: "You created add100 in every iteration of map calls." gosh no they didn't.

Comment: @Kaiido Nvm me, you're right.. confused me `map` with something else for a sec there

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is actually mis-leading

Compare these 3 cases

```
function add100(item) {
  return item + 100;
}

function doSomethingWithNamedFunction(array) {
  return array.map(add100);
}

function doSomethingWithAnonFunction(array) {
  return array.map(function(v) { return i + 100; });
}

function doSomethingWithArrowFunction(array) {
  return array.map(v => i + 100);
}


const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

console.log(doSomethingWithNamedFunction(array));
console.log(doSomethingWithNamedFunction(array));
console.log(doSomethingWithNamedFunction(array));

console.log(doSomethingWithAnonFunction(array));
console.log(doSomethingWithAnonFunction(array));
console.log(doSomethingWithAnonFunction(array));

console.log(doSomethingWithArrowFunction(array));
console.log(doSomethingWithArrowFunction(array));
console.log(doSomethingWithArrowFunction(array));
```

In the first one a closure was created when `add100` was encountered in the file. Each time we call `doSomethingWithNamedFunction` no new closures related to add100 are created.

In the second case `doSomethingWithAnonFunction` one closure related to the anon function is created each time `doSomethingWithAnonFunction` is called

In the third case `doSomethingWithArrowFunction` one closure related to the arrow function is created each time `doSomethingWithArrowFunction` is called. In addition the current value if `this` is bound to the the anon function. How that happens is up to the JavaScript engine. The simplest implementation would create a new function to wrap the anonymous function but I doubt most JavaScript engines do that.

Note though the named function is not special vs anonymous and arrow functions. We can get the same behavior with named functions by moving the named function inside `doSomethingWithNamedFunction`

```
function doSomethingWithNamedFunction(array) {

  function add100(item) {
    return item + 100;
  }

  return array.map(add100);
}
```

Now the same number of closures will be created even for the named case. And visa-versa we can move the anon function creation outside its usage and make it the same as the original named example

```
const anonFn = function(v) { return i + 100; }
function doSomethingWithAnonFunction(array) {
  return array.map(anonFn);
}

const arrowFn = v => i + 100;
function doSomethingWithArrowFunction(array) {
  return array.map(arrowFn);
}
```

Comment: Note that since ES6 the last function will be anonymous only the time it's not yet assigned to the variable (functions are auto-named now)